# Oracle: How do I set a context variable?

Tags: oracle

Here's a user context, and a package that sets a value in it.

```
create or replace context t1_ctx using t1_pkg accessed globally;

create or replace package t1_pkg
as
    procedure setx;
end t1_pkg;

create or replace package body t1_pkg
as
    procedure setx is
    begin
        dbms_session.set_context('t1_ctx','x','1');    
    end;
end t1_pkg;
```

But, it seems that I can't get the context variable set.  Both before and after the call to `setx`, 'x' remains NULL.

```
mh> select sys_context('t1_ctx', 'x') from dual;
sys_context('t1_ctx','x') 
------------------------- 
NULL                      

mh> exec t1_pkg.setx;

mh> select sys_context('t1_ctx', 'x') from dual;
sys_context('t1_ctx','x') 
------------------------- 
NULL                      <---- I expect this should be '1' ???
```

How do I set a variable in my user context?

Comment: You are never calling `setx`

Answer (score 3):

The above works just fine.

```
SQL> create or replace context t1_ctx using t1_pkg accessed globally;

Context created.

SQL>

create or replace package t1_pkg
as
    procedure setx;
end t1_pkg;
/

Package created.

SQL>

create or replace package body t1_pkg
as
    procedure setx is
    begin
        dbms_session.set_context('t1_ctx','x','1');
    end;
end t1_pkg;
/

Package body created.

SQL> select sys_context('t1_ctx', 'x') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('T1_CTX','X')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


SQL> exec t1_pkg.setx;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select sys_context('t1_ctx', 'x') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('T1_CTX','X')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1
```

Comment: Looks like this value is persisted across sessions.
Is there a way to hold a different value for each session / connection?

Comment: @Guest yes, omit the _accessed globally_ part in the CREATE CONTEXT command.